# error: expected ':' before ')' token

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)countdown:(NSTimer *)timer{

    _value -=1;
    if ((_delegate != nil) && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(countdownTicker:didUpdateValue:withAction)]) { // error: expected ':' before ')' token
        [_delegate countdownTicker:self didUpdateValue:_value withAction:ZIMCountdownTickerTickAction];
    }
    if (_value <= 0) {
        [self stop];
        if ((_delegate != nil) && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(countdownTicker:didUpdateValue:withAction)]) { // error: expected ':' before ')' token
            [_delegate countdownTickerDidFinish:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @sidyl and @MarkPowell:Thanks..Did as you told and it worked.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then don't forget to mark an answer as correct…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix it exactly as the error says:

```
... respondsToSelector:@selector(countdownTicker:didUpdateValue:withAction:)]
                                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a ':' at the end of your `withAction` parameter in the selector.